# Convert ulong to 8 byte array in javascript

Tags: javascript, byte

I have an unsigned long in javascript that I'm trying to convert to a byte array (8 bytes obviously for the long.) Here is what I have so far:

```
var deviceId = parseFloat("353268001238563");
var bytes = new Array(7);
for(var k=0;k<8;k++) {
   bytes[k] = value & (255);
   value = value >> 8
}
return bytes;
```

Unfortunately the bytes generated are incorrect. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>>` operator doesn't seem to work with values that can't be represented in a regular 32-bit signed integer as it will wrap.

A hack solution might be to use regular division instead of a bit-shift:

```
value = value / 256;
```

Comment: Any idea how I can achieve this? I'm missing my C# BitConverter.GetBytes function in javascript. :(